# weblock error with NSURLErrorDomain error -999

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurl

I am trying to load twitter link in UIWebview.I have faced NSURLErrorDomain error

```
The operation couldn’t be completed.(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

and I have solved it by writing code

```
if([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled) {**  

return; 

 }
```

in `didFailLoadWithError` delegate method.

After this, I have no problem with NSURLErrorDomain error.But Each time after solving this error app was crashing due to error

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x5f82bf0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use your `UIWebView` or `UIWebViewDelegate` on another thread. 
Using `UIKit` on a thread outside of main will cause a thread lock, and most likely crash.